# set the value of an image based on the value of another image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have an image and a binary image. I want to get a third image that keeps the values of the original image but when the pixel of the binary image is 255, the pixel value will be 180.

I've tried to different ways but neither works (the final images are the same as the original).

```
images[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) ) 
images[n] = cv2.cvtColor(images[n], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(images[n], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        
Binary threshold image
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#First try
img1 = images[n].copy()
img1[mask==255]=(180,180,180)

#Second try
img2 = numpy.where(mask == 255,180,images[n])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use a debugger and take a look at your variables. The problem is just that `cv2.threshold` doesn't return an image! The (obscure) syntax in OpenCV documentation is:

```py
cv.threshold(src, thresh, maxval, type[, dst]) -> retval, dst
```

So it returns a tuple with the threshold value (useful if you are using Otsu thresholding) and the destination image. You just need to capture the correct returned value.

Here is an example of using it:

```py
test = cv2.imread('cat.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
gray[mask > 0] = 180
test[mask > 0] = [ 128, 128, 0]
cv2.imwrite('cat_mask_gray.png', gray)
cv2.imwrite('cat_mask.png', test)
```

Starting from this cute cat: [image: cat.png]

You get this mask: [image: mask.png]

This is the gray result: [image: cat_mask_gray.png]

This is the color result: [image: cat_mask.png]